# Trying to compress files from multiple folders

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have files stored in multiple different folders and I need to make a ZIP archive from all the files in those folders. I have created a simple function using System.IO.Compression, that takes the data from just one folder and makes a ZIP archive, but I can't figure out how to do that for multiple folders. No folders needed in ZIP, just the files from it.

If it can't be done in this library, I can use a different one like DotNetZip or similar.

```
string folder1 = @"c:\ex\ZipFolder1";
string zipPath = @"c:\ex\AllFiles.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folder1, zipPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `DotNetZip`.Just create a `ZipFile` and add files by the method [AddFiles](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/ef7decff-a364-ca8b-6b11-fcace4c84af0.htm)

```
using (var file = new ZipFile())
{
    //fileNames is an array containing the paths of the files from differents folders
    file.AddFiles(fileNames);
    file.Save(zipFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried using AddFile() method of ZipFile Class. Here you can replace 'PathOfFiles' dynamically as per your requirement. 

var fileNames = new string[] { "a.txt", "b.xlsx", "c.png" };
            using (var zip = new ZipFile()){
    foreach (var file in fileNames)
    zip.AddFile(@"PathOfFiles\" + fileName, "");
    zip.Name = "ZipFile";
  var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
            {
                zip.Save(stream);
                stream.Close(); 
            }, "application/zip");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone encountering this today, here's an updated short and simple answer based on Microsoft's docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.createentryfromfile?view=net-6.0

```
static void SaveFilesToZip(string zipTargetPath, string[] filePaths)
{
    using var newZip = ZipFile.Open(zipTargetPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
    {
        newZip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    }
}
```